# Como dar um Tab no cursor no Vs Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Tenho Windows 10 e uso o Vs Code. Eu quero dar tab no meu cursor, mas quando eu aperto a tecla tab, o que acontece é que o cursor passa a selecionar o primeiro item do cabeçalho do terminal (e fica navegando pelos comandos do Vs Code) ao invés de dar um espaço de tabulação.

Como eu posso dar um tab? Terei que editar o comportamento da tecla? Se sim, como faz isso no Vs?

Comment: Isso acontece só dentro do terminal? Vc instalou alguma extensão de formatação ou algo do tipo para o terminal? Já entrou no Json dos Settings ou na lista do Shortcuts para ver o que está atribuído ao Tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Configuração do TAB no VSCode**

Entra no Json dos `Settings` ou na lista do `Shortcuts` para ver o que está atribuído ao Tab. A opção é mudar configurando o uso do Tab nas configurações do VS Code.

Vá em `File > Preferences > Settings` e pesquise por `"Tab"` e verifique o `"editor.tabSize": 2,`

Vc também pode dar um Ctrl+A para selecionar todas as linhas do arquivo. Depois vai no `ctrl + shift + p > indent` e escolhe o formato que vc quer.
A opção é mudar configurando o uso do Tab nas configurações do VS Code.

Você também pode abrir o arquivo `keybindings.json`, na Paleta de comandos `(Ctrl+Shift+P)`, pesquisar por Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON), mas é somente leitura.

**Auto-Identação**

Um dos atalhos para indentar no Visual Studio Code

no windows você usa `Shift + Alt + F`

No Mac é `Shift + Option + F`

E no Linux é `Ctrl + Shift + i`

**Extensões**

Dependendo da linguagem que você estiver usando, você pode baixar algum plugin de Code Formatter pra linguagem especifica que for usar. Basta procurar na galeria de extensões do VS Code: `"SuaLinguagem Formatter"`.

Eu recomendo a Beautify que vc pode encontrar no Market Place do VS Code. [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify)
Ou Prettier dependendo do código que vc quer formatar... [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Para identar com os = no mesmo espaço, temos também a extensão Better Align que faz exatamente isso e vc pode configurar no teclado o atalho que quiser. [Documentação](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwm.better-align)

Vai em `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` E cria seu atalho assim por exemplo:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+i",  "command": "wwm.aligncode",
                           "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" }
```

Answer (score 1):

O que resolveu foi mais ou menos isso abaixo, que a @RebecaNonato falou:

"Você também pode abrir o arquivo keybindings.json, na Paleta de comandos (Ctrl+Shift+P), pesquisar por Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON), mas é somente leitura."

Ao dar Ctrl+shift+p, e buscar por keyboard, eu selecionei "Help: keyboard shortcut reference", e então abriu a lista de comandos configurados.

Lá dizia que o **Ctrl+M** altera o "foco de uso" da tecla tab. **E então ao dar esse comando, a Tab passou a dar um espaço de tabulação mesmo.**